# Content Editable stays the same after changing page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm doing a web app that fetchs some info from the service and displays it in a table. I'm also using pagination. The objective is to receive some data and let the user change it, some of the fields don't have info yet, and the user can add it. The problem is, in this last situation, if the field is null and the user puts some info, after changing page with pagination from react, if in the place of the changed cell its another empty field, the info will stay, although its a different object.

```
export default function Product() {        
      const [resources, setResourcesData] = useState<PaginatedList>();
      const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
      const [itemsPerPage, setItemsPerPage] = useState(5);
      const [sortValue, setSortValue] = useState("ASC");
      const [sortPropertyName, setSortPropertyName] = useState("key");
      const [searchString, setSearchString] = useState("");
      const [searchPropertyName, setSearchPropertyName] = useState("Key");
    
     /*just some info i needed to get the project name*/
      const location = useLocation();
      const str = JSON.stringify(location.state).split('"');
      const prod = str[3];
    
      const fetchItem = async () => {
        let resourcesData: PaginatedList;
        const fetchProducts = await axios.get(${config.SERVER_URL}/Resources, {
          params: {
            project: prod,
            pageIndex: currentPage,
            pageCount: itemsPerPage,
            sortPropertyName: sortPropertyName,
            sortOrder: sortValue,
            searchPropertyName: searchPropertyName,
            searchString: searchString,
          },
        });
        resources?.items.forEach(res => {
        let td = document.getElementById(res.key + res.culture + "comment");
        var div = td?.childNodes.item;
        console.log(div);
        
          
        });
        resourcesData = fetchProducts.data;
        setResourcesData(resourcesData);
      };
    
      const editString = async (resx: IResource) => {
        let resource: IResource;
        let value = document.getElementById(resx.key + "value")?.innerText;
        let comment = document.getElementById(resx.key + "comment")?.innerText;
        if (comment === undefined) {
          comment = "";
        }
        if (value === undefined) {
          value = "";
        }
        console.log(value);
        resource = {
          project: prod,
          key: resx.key,
          value: value,
          comment: comment,
          culture: resx.culture,
        };
        await axios.put(${config.SERVER_URL}/Update, resource);
      };
    
      const nextList = () => {
        setCurrentPage(currentPage + 1);
      };
    
      const previousList = () => {
        setCurrentPage(currentPage - 1);
      };
    
      const onChangePrev = () => {
        if (currentPage == 1) {
          return true;
        }
        return false;
      };
    
      const onChangeNext = () => {
        if (currentPage == resources?.totalPages) {
          checkUndefined();
          return true;
        }
        return false;
      };
    
      const firstList = () => {
        setCurrentPage(1);
      };
    
      const lastList = () => {
        setCurrentPage(resources!.totalPages);
      };
    
      const handleSortValueChange = (
        e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLImageElement, MouseEvent>
      ) => {
        if (e.currentTarget.classList.contains("asc")) {
          e.currentTarget.classList.remove("asc");
    
          e.currentTarget.classList.add("desc");
    
          setSortValue("DESC");
        } else {
          e.currentTarget.classList.remove("desc");
    
          e.currentTarget.classList.add("asc");
    
          setSortValue("ASC");
        }
      };
    
      function checkUndefined() {
    
      }
    
      useEffect(() => {
        fetchItem();
      }, [
        currentPage,
        itemsPerPage,
        sortValue,
        searchString,
        searchPropertyName,
        sortPropertyName,
      ]);
    
      /*
    const indexOfLastItem = currentPage * itemsPerPage;
    const indexOfFirstItem = indexOfLastItem - indexOfLastItem;
    */
    
      if (!resources?.items) {
        return <div>Loading... </div>;
      } else {
        return (
          <div className="App">
            <div style={{ height: "5rem" }}></div>
            <div className="styled-table">
              <div className="div-grande">
                <input
                  placeholder="Search"
                  type="text"
                  name="search"
                  id="search"
                  onChange={(s) => setSearchString(s.target.value)}
                />
                <div className="radio-button">
                  Key
                  <label>
                    <input
                      type="radio"
                      value="key"
                      id="searchByKey"
                      checked={"key" === searchPropertyName}
                      onClick={(n) => setSearchPropertyName("key")}
                    />
                  </label>
                  Value
                  <label>
                    <input
                      type="radio"
                      value="value"
                      name="searchByValue"
                      checked={"value" === searchPropertyName}
                      onClick={(n) => setSearchPropertyName("value")}
                    />
                  </label>
                </div>
                <div className="div-arrow">
                  <img
                    data-testid="sortValue"
                    id="sortImage"
                    className="asc"
                    src="/arrow.svg"
                    alt="sort"
                    title={
                      sortValue
                        ? "Press to ascending order"
                        : "Press to descending order"
                    }
                    onClick={handleSortValueChange}
                  />
                  Order by:
                  <Select
                    className="select-order"
                    isSearchable={false}
                    closeMenuOnSelect={true}
                    id="order"
                    options={[
                      { label: "Key", value: "Key" },
                      { label: "Value", value: "Value" },
                      { label: "Culture", value: "Culture" },
                    ]}
                    defaultValue={{ label: "Key", value: "Key" }}
                    getOptionLabel={(option) => `${option.label}`}
                    getOptionValue={(option) => `${option.value}`}
                    onChange={(n) => setSortPropertyName(n!.value)}
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
              <Table id="table">
                <thead>
                  <th>Key</th>
                  <th>Value</th>
                  <th>Comment</th>
                  <th>Language</th>
                  <th></th>
                </thead>
    
                <tbody>
                  {resources.items.map((resx) => (
                    <tr>
                      <td id={resx.key}>{resx.key}</td>
                      <td id={resx.key + resx.culture + "value"}>
                        <div id="value" contentEditable>
                          {resx.value}
                        </div>
                      </td>
                      <td id={resx.key + resx.culture + "comment"}>
                        <div id="comment" contentEditable>
                          {resx.comment}
                        </div>
                      </td>
                      <td id={resx.key + resx.culture}>{resx.culture}</td>
                      <td>
                        <Button
                          className="myButton"
                          onClick={() => editString(resx)}
                        >
                          Save
                        </Button>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  ))}
                </tbody>
              </Table>
    
              <Select
                className="select"
                isSearchable={false}
                closeMenuOnSelect={true}
                id="count"
                options={[
                  { label: 5, value: 5 },
                  { label: 10, value: 10 },
                  { label: 20, value: 20 },
                  { label: 50, value: 50 },
                  { label: 100, value: 100 },
                ]}
                defaultValue={{ label: 5, value: 5 }}
                getOptionLabel={(option) => `${option.label}`}
                getOptionValue={(option) => `${option.value}`}
                onChange={(n) => setItemsPerPage(n!.value)}
              />
    
              <div>
                <Pagination>
                  <Pagination.First onClick={() => firstList()} />
                  <Pagination.Prev
                    onClick={() => previousList()}
                    id="prev"
                    disabled={onChangePrev()}
                  />
    
                  <Pagination.Next
                    onClick={() => nextList()}
                    id="next"
                    disabled={onChangeNext()}
                  />
                  <Pagination.Last onClick={() => lastList()} />
                </Pagination>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
```

The checkUndefined function was an attempt to clear the row.
Here are some pictures to show better my problem.[image]
I added the "we" in the second row
[image]
And after clicking the button to see the next page of the table the "we" is still there, in that place would be a empty fields.

Comment: Given that this bug is about how resources updates, the fact you've omitted any of the code that sets the resources makes this basically impossible to trace. Any reason you're only sharing a fragment of your code?

Comment: @cefn it was just because im almost certain that the problem is with the contenteditable. but i will edit and post the rest

Comment: That's why they say repro :) https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @cefn i posted the full class without imports

Comment: If you can't make sense of it, then a bunch of strangers on the internet seeing only half the code and trying to compile it in their heads will find it even harder. Please see the definition of minimal reproducible example. Perhaps you could start with forking the React Typescript template( https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-noether-926yf?file=/src/App.tsx ) and add your code until people can see your problem for themselves.